# Filter data in a column and then count

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have recorded a macro to make changes to a sheet. Basically it makes a few changes such as add a column move two columns over and so forth. The thing that I am confused with is adding a small code to give me a count of the total DL and IDL in the MO REAL column L separately and putting the total count on another sheet in the same workbook "Resultados" in cells B17 and C17... Any ideas on how this can be accomplished? Here is the recorded code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DefineDL_IDL()

Dim wbTHMacro As Workbook, wsRegulares As Worksheet, wsRegularesDemitidos As Worksheet, wsTempActivos As Worksheet, _
wsTempJA As Worksheet, wsTempFit As Worksheet, wsTempDemitidos As Worksheet, wsPS As Worksheet, wsResultados As Worksheet, _
wsDLList As Worksheet, wssheet As Worksheet

Sheets("Regulares").Select

Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MO REAL"
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Columns("Q:Q").Select
    Selection.Cut

    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("K1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
        "INATIVE"
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Range("F5").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=11
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'DL List'!RC[-11]:R[32]C[-10],2,0)"
    Range("L2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L5890")
    Range("L2:L5890").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="DL"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    Range("L23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DL"
    Range("L23").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L25").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=12
    Range("L4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "G&A", "MOH", "IDL", "Other MOH"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    Range("L7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IDL"
    Range("L7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L15").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("L7").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Regulares").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Regulares").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("K1:K5890"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=12
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=11
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("J2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are counting the times "DL" and "IDL" occur...

'Count DL and IDL

```
count_DL = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("L:L"), "DL")

count_IDL = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("L:L"), "IDL")
```

'Paste results in Resultados sheet

```
Worksheets("Resultados").Range("B17") = count_DL

Worksheets("Resultados").Range("C17") = count_IDL
```

Comment: I am counting the times they occur. When adding this code it gives me a variable not defined error... `count_DL =`

Comment: Dim count_DL As Integer, count_IDL As Integer or remove Option Explicit

Comment: I actually used count_DL As Integer, count_IDL As Integer... is there a difference?

Comment: BTW, as pointed out by MatthewHagemann regarding this code, there is no need for variables. I was just trying to make it more clear in case you wanted to do something more.

Comment: I guess that's correct also but in his case how would we tell the difference between Dls and IDLs in the same column?

Comment: His code wouldn't... it was a little unclear what you were trying to do.

Comment: Another question. I have another 3 sheets in the same file that I have to do the same procedure for move the columns over add the MO Real column and so forth, but the columns I need to move are different instead of K and Q its K and P and the same process needs to be done for all three sheets at the same time. Is there a possible way to adapt this macro to do that and give me the count of DLs and IDLs for all three sheets already summed and posted on the Resultados Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing without understanding a broader picture of what you're doing.  All you need to do to get a count and put it in another sheet is:

> Sheets("AnotherSheet").Range("B13") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("G:G"))

Comment: Basically I have to determine in the MO REAL column L weather an employee is DL or IDL thats why the vlookup in the previous code... count the number of DL employees and IDL employees and paste the total count of each in another worksheet...